# How to create a new JSON tree with typescript?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an Ionic (Angular) geolocation tracker mobile app. The location tracking already works pretty well. But now I want to store the geolocations in routes. For now every dataset (accuracy, long, lat...) will be saved separately in the Firebase Realtime DB.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Goal is to have the structure like this:

```
-geolocations
    - routeId
        - trackingId
            - accuracy
            - long
            - lat
            - timeStamp
            - uId
```

The old structure looks like this:
[image]

**tracking.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { GeolocationService } from '../../app/geolocation.service';
import { UserService } from '../../app/user.service';
import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia/ngx';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tracking',
  templateUrl: './tracking.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tracking.page.scss'],
})
export class TrackingPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('map', { static: true }) mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  markers = [];
  geoLocations: any;

  watchLocationUpdates: any;
  isWatching: boolean;
  interval: any;

  geoLatitude: number;
  geoLongitude: number;
  geoAccuracy: number;
  timeStamp: any;
  uId: string;
  trackingId: string;

  constructor(
    private geolocation: Geolocation,
    public geolocationService: GeolocationService,
    public userService: UserService,
    private insomnia: Insomnia,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public alertController: AlertController,
    public appComponent: AppComponent,
    private storage: Storage
    ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log('navigator.geolocation works well');
    }

    this.appComponent.isLoggedIn = true;

    this.loadMap();
      console.log('this.loadMap() called');
  }

  loadMap() {
    const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.141558, 11.568210);
    const mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      fullscreenControl: false,
      zoomControl: false
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
  }

  // Start location watch
  watchLocation() {
    this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Standort Tracking wird initialisiert...',
      duration: 5000,
    }).then((res) => {
      res.present();
    });
    const options = {
      maximumAge: 3000,
      timeout: 5000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
    };
    this.isWatching = true;
    this.insomnia.keepAwake()
    .then(
      () => console.log('this.insomnia.keepAwake(): success')
    );
    this.trackingId =  Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.uId = this.userService.uId;
      if (this.appComponent.userName !== '') { // Makes sure that username is loaded from db
      this.watchLocationUpdates = this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options);
      this.watchLocationUpdates.then((resp) => {

        this.geoLocations = resp.coords;
        this.geoLatitude = resp.coords.latitude;
        this.geoLongitude = resp.coords.longitude;
        this.geoAccuracy = Math.trunc(resp.coords.accuracy);
        this.timeStamp = Date.now();

        this.geolocationService.insertUserGeolocation({
          trackingId: this.trackingId,
          latitude: this.geoLatitude,
          longitude: this.geoLongitude,
          accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
          timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
          uId: this.uId
          }).subscribe((response) => {
            localStorage.setItem('lastLocation', JSON.stringify({
              trackingId: this.trackingId,
              latitude: this.geoLatitude,
              longitude: this.geoLongitude,
              accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
              timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
              uId: this.uId
              }));
            console.log(`user location data inserted in FB`, {
              trackingId: this.trackingId,
              latitude: this.geoLatitude,
              longitude: this.geoLongitude,
              accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
              timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
              uId: this.uId
              });
          });

        const position = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
        this.map.setCenter(position);
        this.map.setZoom(16);

        this.markers.map(marker => marker.setMap(null));
        this.markers = [];
        const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: this.map,
          icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 13,
            fillColor: '#1CA0EC',
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeColor: 'white',
            strokeWeight: 2
          },
            position: latLng
        });
        this.markers.push(marker);
      });
      } else {
      this.stopLocationWatch();
      }
    }, 3000);
  }

  // Stop location watch
  stopLocationWatch() {
    this.isWatching = false;
    console.log('this.isWatching = ', this.isWatching);
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    console.log('this.interval', this.interval);
    // this.watchLocationUpdatesSub.unsubscribe();
    this.loadMap();
    this.locationStopAlert();
    this.insomnia.allowSleepAgain()
      .then(
       () => console.log('this.insomnia.allowSleepAgain(): success'),
    );
  }

  async locationStopAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Das Standort Tracking wurde beendet',
      // message: 'This is an alert message.',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add an example of the old json structure?, is trackingId unique in a route?

Comment: Yes the trackingId should be unique. So that every route can have several data sets (accuracy, long, lat, etc.). I might also have to change the data service to store the routeId in the DB first and afterwards the trackingIds with the related data sets. But I don't know how to import properties of pages (e.g. tracking.page) to data services.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this code I made for you should help you convert from the old format to the new one.

```
const geolocations = {
  routeId1: [
    { trackingId: 1, timeStamp: 1, accuracy: 1, longitude: 1, latitude: 1, uId: 1 },
    { trackingId: 1, timeStamp: 2, accuracy: 2, longitude: 2, latitude: 2, uId: 2 },
    { trackingId: 2, timeStamp: 1, accuracy: 3, longitude: 3, latitude: 3, uId: 3 },
    { trackingId: 2, timeStamp: 2, accuracy: 4, longitude: 4, latitude: 4, uId: 4 }
  ],
  routeId2: [
    { trackingId: 3, timeStamp: 1, accuracy: 5, longitude: 5, latitude: 5, uId: 5 },
    { trackingId: 4, timeStamp: 1, accuracy: 6, longitude: 6, latitude: 6, uId: 6 },
    { trackingId: 4, timeStamp: 2, accuracy: 7, longitude: 7, latitude: 7, uId: 7 },
    { trackingId: 4, timeStamp: 3, accuracy: 8, longitude: 8, latitude: 8, uId: 8 }
  ]
};
const newGeolocations = {};
const routesIds = Object.keys(geolocations);
for (const routeId of routesIds) {
  const route= geolocations[routeId];
  if (!newGeolocations.hasOwnProperty(route)) {
    newGeolocations[routeId] = {}
  }
  for (const loc of route) {
    if (!newGeolocations[routeId].hasOwnProperty(loc.trackingId)) {
      newGeolocations[routeId][loc.trackingId] = []
    }
    newGeolocations[routeId][loc.trackingId].push({
      accuracy: loc.accuracy,
      longitude: loc.longitude,
      latitude: loc.latitude,
      timeStamp: loc.timeStamp,
      uId: loc.uId
    });
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newGeolocations));
```

This is the result that I get in console,

```
{
"routeId1":
    {"1":[
        {"accuracy":1,"longitude":1,"latitude":1,"timeStamp":1,"uId":1},
        {"accuracy":2,"longitude":2,"latitude":2,"timeStamp":2,"uId":2}
    ],
    "2":[
        {"accuracy":3,"longitude":3,"latitude":3,"timeStamp":1,"uId":3},
        {"accuracy":4,"longitude":4,"latitude":4,"timeStamp":2,"uId":4}
    ]},
"routeId2":{
    "3":[
        {"accuracy":5,"longitude":5,"latitude":5,"timeStamp":1,"uId":5}
    ],
    "4":[
        {"accuracy":6,"longitude":6,"latitude":6,"timeStamp":1,"uId":6},
        {"accuracy":7,"longitude":7,"latitude":7,"timeStamp":2,"uId":7},
        {"accuracy":8,"longitude":8,"latitude":8,"timeStamp":3,"uId":8}
    ]}
}
```

Let me know if it helps you.